# join strings from a list by condition

Tags: python, list

I have this *list of strings* :

```
listInfos = ['D D R: 17/10/2018', 'nothing past this date', 'D D R: 4/10/2018', 'D D R: 2/10/2018']
```

and I want to **sort** it such that the result will be :

```
parsedList = ['D D R: 17/10/2018 & nothing past this date', 'D D R: 4/10/2018', 'D D R: 2/10/2018']
```

Every element after a `'D D R ..'` should be *associated* with it **until** we have a **new** `'D D R ..'`

Is there a quick command to do such a thing ? 
I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
parsedList = []
for i in range(len(listeInfos)):
        tmpList = []
        if re.match(r'^D D R', listeInfos[i]):
                tmpList.append(listeInfos[i])
                while not(re.match(r'^D D R', listeInfos[i+1])):
                        tmpList.append(listeInfos[i])
                        i += 1
                else:
                        parsedList.append(tmpList)
                        break
                break
        i = j
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question**: Every element after a 'D D R ..' should be associated with it until we have a new 'D D R ..'

Don't battle with Indizies!
For example:

> **Note**: `listInfos` **has** to start with **'D D R'**!

```
listInfos = ['D D R: 17/10/2018', 'nothing past this date', 'D D R: 4/10/2018', 'D D R: 2/10/2018']

parsedList = []

# Loop the List of Strings
for s in listInfos:
    # Condition not
    if not s.startswith('D D R'):
        # if True concat 's' with the last String in the List
        parsedList[-1] += " " + s
    else:
        # Append 's' as a new String to the List
        parsedList.append(s)

for s in parsedList:
    print(s)
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> D D R: 17/10/2018 nothing past this date
> D D R: 4/10/2018
> D D R: 2/10/2018`
> ```

***Tested with Python:3.5.3***

Answer (score 1):

If you want the list to contain only the sorted dates, use:

```
parsedList = sorted([date for date in listInfos if date.startswith('D D R')],
                key=lambda date: int(date[-4:] + date[-7:-5] + date[-10:-8]), reverse=True)
```

Explanation:

1. Here we insert the dates that starts with your custom prefix 'D D R':

   ```
   [date for date in listInfos if date.startswith('D D R')]
   ```
2. Now, we sort said list, by date, while knowing that reverse dates as an integer can be the key, because, for example, that: 20181012 < 20181226

   ```
   key=lambda date: int(date[-4:] + date[-7:-5] + date[-10:-8]
   ```
3. Next, we reverse the result, to be in an ascending order (optional)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it in one expression. I doubt it is readable but just for fun:

```
from itertools import takewhile

parsedList = [
    (el + ' & ' + ' '.join(
            takewhile(lambda x: not x.startswith('D D R'), listInfos[pos + 1:])
        )
     ).rstrip(' &')
    for pos, el in enumerate(listInfos) if el.startswith('D D R')
]

print(parsedList)
# ['D D R: 17/10/2018 & nothing past this date', 'D D R: 4/10/2018', 'D D R: 2/10/2018']
```

We get a sublist between two DDR's via `itertools.takewhile` starting from index next after the current (the index is fetched with `enumerate`)